# responsive inline block enquiry

Tags: css, fluid

I need some advice on this issue i'm having. In the `jsfiddle` below, I'm trying to create a responsive `grid` layout. The issue with what i have is, i would like the text to be in the middle of each individual `grid`. I've tried bumping it using margin-top but instead of the images stacking onto each other while resizing, the images are overlapping each other. The end result desired will be to have the text aligned center onto the image and have no gaps on all sides of the `grid` when resizing according to various screen resolution.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kelvinchow/VaDS9/

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: green;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: red;
}
.box-img img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}
.box-title {
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: helvetica, san serif;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="http://airinlee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/thumbnail6.png">
        </div>
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="http://airinlee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/thumbnail6.png">
        </div>
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="http://airinlee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/thumbnail6.png">
        </div>
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="http://airinlee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/thumbnail6.png">
        </div>
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/VaDS9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this:

[image]

Fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/osazav/1.

With this markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="tl" class="box">
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tr" class="box">
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bl" class="box">
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
    <div id="br" class="box">
        <p class="box-title">howdy</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this css:

```
div.box {
    background: url('http://airinlee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/thumbnail6.png');
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
div.box p.box-title {
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -10px -20px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
div.box#tl { top: 0%; left: 0%; }
div.box#tr { top: 0%; left: 50%; }
div.box#bl { top: 50%; left: 0%; }
div.box#br { top: 50%; left: 50%; }
```

Comment: If this is answered your question, please consider accepting it as an answer, it might help other people.